# ssh with key content instead of identity_file

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Instead of `ssh -i mykey.pem` I would like to pass the *content* of `mykey.pem` to the ssh command.

Is that possible somehow?

*Background: the `mykey.pem` is stored encryptedly. I would like to decrypt it on the fly (in a CI tool) and pass it to ssh. Decrypting it and passing the path to the decrypted key would make it accessible to someone with disc access.*

Comment: You do know OpenSSH itself supports password-encrypted key files? Historically it used OpenSSL's 'legacy' format which has a very poor PBKDF, but all versions also support PKCS8 (via OpenSSL PEM API) and versions 6.5 up (since 2014) support OpenSSH's own 'new format'.

Comment: Thanks. We are using `ansible-vault` at the moment. I am pretty happy with it.

Comment: `echo "$KEY" | ssh -i /dev/stdin username@host command` — Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041688/specify-private-key-in-ssh-as-string/16102792#16102792

Answer (score 3):

You can use **process substitution** (pseudo file) in bash like :

`ssh -i <( some command to generate file contents ) host`

examples:

`ssh -i <( cat /tmp/key.id ) host`
`ssh -i <( echo key contents ) host`

You can read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution

EDIT :

After reading your question second time I'm not sure if this is what you wanted

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't work for some reason. I am getting `Warning: Identity file /dev/fd/63 not accessible: No such file or directory.`. This is the command I am executing: `ssh -i <( cat /path>/key.pem ) <host>`. Executing just `cat /<path>/key.pem` works and this example: `diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` works too. bash version is 4.3.11.

Comment: @kev Did you ever find a solution? Process substitution isn't working for me either to pass the identity to ssh.

Comment: @KingChungHuang unfortunately not, haven't pursued it any further. I am temporarily writing the file to disc and deleting it afterwards. That workaround seemed good enough.